# Why object is white in viewport and textured when I hit "P"?

Tags: rendering, texturing, game-engine, 3d-view

Why object is white in viewport and textured when I hit <kbd>P</kbd> ?

I'm in *GLSL* shading mode and I can't see the object textured in the *Game Engine*.

[image]

Comment: Can you post your .blend file?

Comment: @godolomn add your mix file, I know it is but I need to see your shading settings to correct it, without the file it is harder to recreate your problem and I could not assure you that the solution I give is correct